# deadobject exception while playing youtube video

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am using youtube video player api for playing youtube video in my app, but I am getting the following deadobject exception error.

Here is the **logcat**

```
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535): java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.eo.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:236)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:564)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:235)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12086)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2772)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2772)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3891)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3866)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3798)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.b(Unknown Source)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.h(Unknown Source)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown Source)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1102)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1116)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.b.a.be.a(SourceFile:221)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.eo.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:233)
10-31 11:14:54.670: E/AndroidRuntime(13535):    ... 22 more
```

I have followed this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/simple-example-using-youtube-android.html) for development.

Why is this error ??

Comment: I guess this seems to be a bug. Check this : https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5431

Comment: till now no fixes are provided???

Comment: I guess no.You can post your issue on that site and comment on that.Hope they come up with the resolution.

Comment: Thanks:). but i have a doubt. how are the other apps which are using youtube video player api and already in play store, how the video is playing in it.

Comment: I am not sure but there might be change in API or something like change of OS versions.

Comment: Checkout my answer there might be a problem with the ttf 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23516013/2751529

Answer (score 1):

use loadVideo(video_id) instead of cueVideo(video_id), this helps me