# DeadObjectException on android app

Tags: java, android, memory-management, android-activity

Sometimes I start an `Activity` of my app, or switch fast between `Fragment`s of a `ViewPager` which is in that specific `Activity`, I got `DeadObjectException` like this:

```
W/ActivityManager(  669): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:776)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2501)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2375)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2040)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9667)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9560)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:10205)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9756)
W/ActivityManager(  669):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86
```

and app crashes. I also got some unusual logs like this:

```
F/libc    (24088): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1), thread 24115 (Thread-1047)
I/DEBUG   (23974): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (23974): Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (23974): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   (23974): pid: 24088, tid: 24115, name: Thread-1047  >>> com.somthing.blah <<<
I/DEBUG   (23974): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000020
I/DEBUG   (23974):     r0 77205ca0  r1 00000020  r2 77205ca0  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     r4 77205ca0  r5 756f7f40  r6 00000000  r7 75711d4c
I/DEBUG   (23974):     r8 75e5db10  r9 75711d44  sl 756f7f50  fp 75e5db24
I/DEBUG   (23974):     ip 733efb10  sp 75e5db00  lr 40a4fc3f  pc 00000020  cpsr 400b0010
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d4  0f0000000f000000  d5  050000000f000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d6  0500000005000000  d7  0500000005000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d16 3ea086314bf691da  d17 eddf2c9e110286d5
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d18 006500670022005b  d19 0074006100430074
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d20 0067006f006c0061  d21 002c002200650075
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d22 0022002c00220022  d23 002c002200610066
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d24 4000000000000000  d25 547d42aea2879f2e
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d26 40f86a0000000000  d27 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d28 40f86a0000000000  d29 0000000000000001
I/DEBUG   (23974):     d30 4024000000000000  d31 4000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (23974):     scr 60000010
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #00  pc 00000020  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #01  pc 00079c3d  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup+28)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #02  pc 00079e15  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (EVP_MD_CTX_destroy+4)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #03  pc 0001ea50  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #04  pc 0004f65f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #05  pc 00027ee0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #06  pc 0002f3d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #07  pc 0002ca7c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #08  pc 00061adb  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #09  pc 00061aff  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #10  pc 000567eb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #11  pc 0000d190  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #12  pc 0000d328  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): stack:
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dac0  1e800005  
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dac4  41586719  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dac8  759674f0  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dacc  756f7f40  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dad0  415866f5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dad4  733e41db  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dad8  75e5daec  [stack:24115]
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dadc  733e5e09  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dae0  00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dae4  733e601d  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dae8  00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5daec  759674f0  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5daf0  1e800005  
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5daf4  41e25968  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5daf8  417a2298  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5dafc  756f7f40  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #00  75e5db00  77205ca0  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (23974):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #01  75e5db00  77205ca0  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5db04  40a4fe19  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (EVP_MD_CTX_destroy+8)
I/DEBUG   (23974):     #02  75e5db08  6d7897b0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (23974):          75e5db0c  41558a54  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+120)
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near r0:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205c80 77199488 771a3118 771a31f0 771a31f0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205c90 0000001b 3f800000 00000000 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205ca0 775a1110 00000020 00000020 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cb0 00000001 00000000 00000020 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cc0 730dbd0c 72fa1cee 000003d4 72a82591  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cd0 75752d68 00000001 00000000 0000001b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205ce0 732d5098 75718fa0 77176e18 75735358  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cf0 00000000 0000001b 73268c08 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d00 729967b9 73340f20 00000018 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d10 730db385 72f9b871 00000047 72a2cdbb  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d20 75752d68 00000002 746e6f63 00000013  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d30 732675e0 00000002 721fc331 0000004b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d40 73268780 732687d4 00000002 77205d88  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d50 77176e18 77205d30 721fc0a5 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d70 00000000 77205d98 77205d40 771f2ad8  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205c80 77199488 771a3118 771a31f0 771a31f0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205c90 0000001b 3f800000 00000000 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205ca0 775a1110 00000020 00000020 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cb0 00000001 00000000 00000020 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cc0 730dbd0c 72fa1cee 000003d4 72a82591  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cd0 75752d68 00000001 00000000 0000001b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205ce0 732d5098 75718fa0 77176e18 75735358  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cf0 00000000 0000001b 73268c08 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d00 729967b9 73340f20 00000018 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d10 730db385 72f9b871 00000047 72a2cdbb  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d20 75752d68 00000002 746e6f63 00000013  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d30 732675e0 00000002 721fc331 0000004b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d40 73268780 732687d4 00000002 77205d88  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d50 77176e18 77205d30 721fc0a5 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d70 00000000 77205d98 77205d40 771f2ad8  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near r4:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205c80 77199488 771a3118 771a31f0 771a31f0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205c90 0000001b 3f800000 00000000 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205ca0 775a1110 00000020 00000020 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cb0 00000001 00000000 00000020 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cc0 730dbd0c 72fa1cee 000003d4 72a82591  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cd0 75752d68 00000001 00000000 0000001b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205ce0 732d5098 75718fa0 77176e18 75735358  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205cf0 00000000 0000001b 73268c08 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d00 729967b9 73340f20 00000018 00000023  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d10 730db385 72f9b871 00000047 72a2cdbb  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d20 75752d68 00000002 746e6f63 00000013  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d30 732675e0 00000002 721fc331 0000004b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d40 73268780 732687d4 00000002 77205d88  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d50 77176e18 77205d30 721fc0a5 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d60 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     77205d70 00000000 77205d98 77205d40 771f2ad8  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f20 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f30 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 00000008 0000045b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f40 6e9093d8 75711d44 6d78c6a8 6e9cf000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f50 00000014 00000007 75e5dc40 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f60 75e5dc94 00000013 00000000 41558bc0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f70 00000000 00000000 6c870270 7570e300  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f80 00000000 00000000 00000001 00004000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f90 00000000 756f8398 41558bc0 4155db00  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fa0 00000000 41561bfc 41561c70 41561b20  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fb0 41561b40 41561b9c 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fc0 7716efc0 00000028 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fd0 00000000 00000006 00002000 415ec9fc  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fe0 00000000 00000000 00000001 75712008  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7ff0 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f8000 00000003 6e5c7fe8 6e5c7fe8 00000006  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f8010 6e5c8002 6d7bdb10 4506b31a 95582e61  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near r7:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d2c 00000000 75711d60 6e909384 6d7897b0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d3c 00000000 00000000 77205ca0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d4c 75711d88 6e909484 6d78c6a8 6e909384  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d5c 00000000 77205ca0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d6c 00000000 4193b628 75711da0 6e90ac6a  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d7c 6d78c838 6e909484 00000000 4193b628  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d8c 75711de8 6e90af7e 6d8119b0 6e90ac6a  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d9c 00000000 41db28e0 00000000 41db28b8  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711dac 41db2890 4193b628 6d4b7c58 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711dbc 00000000 4193b740 41cbcf10 00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711dcc 0000006b 00000014 75711e2c 6e90b0a8  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711ddc 6d811a28 6e90af7e 00000000 41cbcf10  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711dec 0000007f 41ebe038 41e4a630 00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711dfc 0000006b 00000014 00000000 4193b740  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711e0c 4188c5d0 00000000 00000010 75711e54  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711e1c 6e9276f8 6d811b40 6e90b0a8 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5daf0 1e800005 41e25968 417a2298 756f7f40  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db00 77205ca0 40a4fe19 6d7897b0 41558a54  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db10 75711d44 00000001 00000008 417a2298  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db20 0000006b 41589663 75711d44 6e84fe63  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db30 733e3f5f 756f7f50 415ec2c8 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db40 1f400001 00000000 003b4c00 4012c384  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db50 41539328 415ae7d9 00000000 415e7c6c  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db60 4012c384 00000014 415ec2c8 4012c384  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db70 00000014 415650f4 00000001 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db80 6d4aa940 6e842b54 00000001 6e967224  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db90 00000001 417a2298 0000003c 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dba0 6d7897b0 6e965758 75e5dbf4 00000038  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbb0 00000001 415a7433 6e965758 6e8da484  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbc0 417a2298 6e965758 6e9cf000 000014b9  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbd0 00000002 4012c384 6d4aad10 415a789b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbe0 75e5dbf4 6e965758 75e5dbf4 415a7e91  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d24 6e909484 6d78c6a8 00000000 75711d60  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d34 6e909384 6d7897b0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d44 77205ca0 00000000 75711d88 6e909484  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d54 6d78c6a8 6e909384 00000000 77205ca0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d64 00000000 00000000 00000000 4193b628  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d74 75711da0 6e90ac6a 6d78c838 6e909484  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d84 00000000 4193b628 75711de8 6e90af7e  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711d94 6d8119b0 6e90ac6a 00000000 41db28e0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711da4 00000000 41db28b8 41db2890 4193b628  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711db4 6d4b7c58 00000000 00000000 4193b740  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711dc4 41cbcf10 00000014 0000006b 00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711dd4 75711e2c 6e90b0a8 6d811a28 6e90af7e  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711de4 00000000 41cbcf10 0000007f 41ebe038  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711df4 41e4a630 00000014 0000006b 00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711e04 00000000 4193b740 4188c5d0 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75711e14 00000010 75711e54 6e9276f8 6d811b40  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f30 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 00000008 0000045b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f40 6e9093d8 75711d44 6d78c6a8 6e9cf000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f50 00000014 00000007 75e5dc40 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f60 75e5dc94 00000013 00000000 41558bc0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f70 00000000 00000000 6c870270 7570e300  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f80 00000000 00000000 00000001 00004000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7f90 00000000 756f8398 41558bc0 4155db00  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fa0 00000000 41561bfc 41561c70 41561b20  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fb0 41561b40 41561b9c 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fc0 7716efc0 00000028 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fd0 00000000 00000006 00002000 415ec9fc  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7fe0 00000000 00000000 00000001 75712008  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f7ff0 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f8000 00000003 6e5c7fe8 6e5c7fe8 00000006  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f8010 6e5c8002 6d7bdb10 4506b31a 95582e61  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     756f8020 f7d042ed f7d041e7 4506b31e 88a0767c  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db04 40a4fe19 6d7897b0 41558a54 75711d44  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db14 00000001 00000008 417a2298 0000006b  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db24 41589663 75711d44 6e84fe63 733e3f5f  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db34 756f7f50 415ec2c8 00000000 1f400001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db44 00000000 003b4c00 4012c384 41539328  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db54 415ae7d9 00000000 415e7c6c 4012c384  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db64 00000014 415ec2c8 4012c384 00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db74 415650f4 00000001 00000001 6d4aa940  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db84 6e842b54 00000001 6e967224 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db94 417a2298 0000003c 00000001 6d7897b0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dba4 6e965758 75e5dbf4 00000038 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbb4 415a7433 6e965758 6e8da484 417a2298  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbc4 6e965758 6e9cf000 000014b9 00000002  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbd4 4012c384 6d4aad10 415a789b 75e5dbf4  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbe4 6e965758 75e5dbf4 415a7e91 00000014  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbf4 6d4aad10 000002d8 415a4663 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efaf0 40109e65 400f23ed 400fe298 40a33ab5  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb00 40109919 40a0f431 40a84dc5 40a54e75  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb10 40a4fe11 40a4f9e5 40a13a8d 40a4612d  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb20 40a45dd1 40a46b25 40a3ee65 40a4a10d  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb30 400f0fd5 40ae8e7d 400ec7d8 400ec8d0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb40 40a5d3d5 40ae86fd 40139927 400da559  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb50 402ca5b5 40a52491 40a4aded 40a4ac61  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb60 40a4ac01 40a4b169 40a4d1f9 401034a5  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb70 40a4d1d9 40a4d2bd 400ebc19 400f13ad  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb80 400efecd 402ca6f5 40ae8ef9 40aebdb1  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efb90 40a84cd5 40a1d4b9 40a1d5a1 40a84d1d  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efba0 40a2071d 40a16991 40a191a1 40a84475  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efbb0 40a78135 40a1f189 40a229b1 40a52dc1  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efbc0 40a22a55 40a128b5 40a53405 40a43345  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efbd0 40a43695 40a42ec5 40a430c9 40a434e1  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     733efbe0 40a42e4d 40a432dd 40a5d279 40a432e9  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dae0 00000014 733e601d 00000014 759674f0  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5daf0 1e800005 41e25968 417a2298 756f7f40  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db00 77205ca0 40a4fe19 6d7897b0 41558a54  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db10 75711d44 00000001 00000008 417a2298  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db20 0000006b 41589663 75711d44 6e84fe63  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db30 733e3f5f 756f7f50 415ec2c8 00000000  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db40 1f400001 00000000 003b4c00 4012c384  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db50 41539328 415ae7d9 00000000 415e7c6c  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db60 4012c384 00000014 415ec2c8 4012c384  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db70 00000014 415650f4 00000001 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db80 6d4aa940 6e842b54 00000001 6e967224  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5db90 00000001 417a2298 0000003c 00000001  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dba0 6d7897b0 6e965758 75e5dbf4 00000038  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbb0 00000001 415a7433 6e965758 6e8da484  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbc0 417a2298 6e965758 6e9cf000 000014b9  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     75e5dbd0 00000002 4012c384 6d4aad10 415a789b  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   (23974): 
I/DEBUG   (23974): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc1c 0006a292 4604b510 b1e86820 b1406a00  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc2c 21024620 fc14f003 6820b918 46206a01  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc3c 68204788 6c40b180 68e0b170 4620b160  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc4c f0032104 b938fc05 68e06821 f00a6c49  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc5c 68e0f81b ffc2f009 b1086920 fac0f006  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc6c b1086860 fff6f7fa 46212000 0f10f841  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc7c 0050efc0 20016048 0a8ff944 bf00bd10  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc8c 4800e92d 0050efc0 46032200 2f10f843  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fc9c f940605a f0000a8f e8bdf803 bf008800  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fcac 48f0e92d 460db082 b3254604 29006829  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fcbc 6868d021 f7fab118 b360ff9d 68206829  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fccc 42882600 4620d104 68e62104 fbb6f003  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fcdc f7ff4620 edd5ff9f f9650b04 edc42a8f  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fcec f9440b04 68e82a8f 6821b388 b3706c48  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fcfc 60e6b1e6 f44fe026 48257194 226f9100  
I/DEBUG   (23974):     40a4fd0c 44794927 20061843 f7fd216e 2000f8b7
```

Most of the time I also got these errors afterwards:

```
W/Binder  (  899): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
W/Binder  (  899): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/Binder  (  899):  at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
W/Binder  (  899):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
W/Binder  (  899):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
W/Binder  (  899):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/InputMethodManagerService(  652): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 14221 uid 10105
```

Each `Fragment` of the aforementioned `ViewPager` loads data from net, and shows them. I'm using Volley as request manager. One more detail, I'm using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in that `ViewPager`.

What does it mean? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using any native libraries in your application?

Comment: The `DeadObjectException` is a symptom of another problem, not a problem itself.

Comment: @DavidWasser: nope, I don't use any native libraries. It's just pure android.

Comment: Then I don't really understand. Normally your Dalvik VM should not crash and usually it isn't possible for you to write code that will crash the VM. Do you see anything else in the logcat? Please check if there is anything else there that could be useful.

Comment: I checked, it seems that the only part of logcat which is related to this issue is what I've posted.

Comment: Well, you should see if you can narrow down roughly where it is crashing (add logging to narrow this down) and then post the code where you think it is crashing. It looks like it may be memory allocation related.

Comment: Do you get these errors on a specific device? multiple devices?

Comment: I usually get them on my Nexus 4, with both custom (CM11) and stock roms. Also on Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: @DavidWasser: Sir, I added some details.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Unfortunately it isn't much help because these are just after-effects of the crash. We need to find out what is causing the crash and the logs don't show that.

Comment: Are you programatically killing your application anywhere in the code ?

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari Were you able to solve this? I am getting similar exception.

Answer (score 41):

[DeadObjectException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html#DeadObjectException%28%29) - The object you are calling has died because its hosting process no longer exists.

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573557/how-to-fix-android-os-deadobjectexception-android-x):

> Does this problem happen every time you debug your project?
>
> Override your service's `onDestroy()` method and watch what event flow
> leads to it. If you catch `DeadObjectException` without going through
> this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.

As you are using web API in your fragment so sometimes that will send multiple requests on the server and in terms of response, you are getting `@null`.

```
W/Binder  (  899): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
W/Binder  (  899): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: I don't have any service, but I'm doing net jobs in fragments. It could be that. I'll try to play with it a little. thanks.

Comment: I removed fragments, and tried to use views in viewpager, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Get null mean you have to debug your code, & for that  try catch will help you

Comment: Yes it happen because its not with the problem of your business logic(code) @KeyhanAsghari

Comment: How to overcome this problem ? How to resolve this issue ? Please suggest.

Comment: Lol, I notice an uncanny resemblance (like exact wording) with my 5-years-older answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573557/how-to-fix-android-os-deadobjectexception-android-x/1574355#1574355 :)

Answer (score 5):

**DeadObjectException** extends RemoteException

This Exception means , The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists. And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037093/android-dead-object-exception) link for your reference based on DeadObjectException.

Comment: I know, but what it can be? I'm not doing any interprocess job when/where this error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

In my app i found this bug , but the great thing about this exception is which doesn't occurs in all the devices

after doing lot of R&D i resolved it by removing Typeface , this might be because of ttf which i was using from assets folder 
Please try comment the typeface and test it hope it will work for sure

When i Got this DeadObjectException my component code looks like this

```
public class TextViewCust extends TextView {

private Context context;
private AttributeSet attrs;
private int defStyle;

public TextViewCust (Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
    init();
} 

 public TextViewCust (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      this.context=context;
      this.attrs=attrs;
      init();
 }

public TextViewCust (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      this.context=context;
      this.attrs=attrs;
      this.defStyle=defStyle;
      init();
 }

private void init() {
            //This is the line where i got dead Object Exception 
        Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "telugu.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(font);
  }
```

**Note:** When i commented the code in init method i never got that exception even a single time

Comment: If you use Typeface.CreateFromAsset on API22 the app randomly crashes with a DeadObjectException (At least this has ben my experience)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exception while running the emulator for a Pixel. However when I ran the same code on a live Samsung 6 with Android 7, the issue was never repeated.  After rebooting my macbook the issue was resolved - I suspect that it often occurs with emulators that have been running for a while on a machine that has been running a while.

TLDR; Reboot your machine.

Comment: I'm getting this on device.

Answer (score 2):

Getting this issue after using Database Inspector too. Restart Android Studio worked.

Comment: Your answer is same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66568264/12215054)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this when I did not called my own method in the onCreate method of the Activity like the init() method in  sample code in the answer below. So I have to put all my code inside the onCreate. From there you will see what is the culprit like a NullPointerException for example but your code will run smoothly already.

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error after using Database Inspector that has been introduced with Android Studio.
Restarting Android Studio and not running Database Inspector fixed the issue for me.

Also try removing the code_cache folder using the Device File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same problem several times. I saw this log entry shortly before the crash:

```
ActivityManager: stop com.google.android.webview
```

My best guess: if your app uses a WebView somewhere and the WebView (Android System WebView) gets a update by Google Play Store (or crashed) while your app is running, this crash can happen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case wrong java_home was the reason.
I tried with:

- react-native v0.70.9
- Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2
- Java 17
  => correct Java Version for this case is Java 11

May it help some others!

Answer (score 0):

DeadObjectException in my case was lack of memory.

Apparently there was a endless "recursion" in the app on the other thread which drained all the memory.

Answer (score -3):

Check if you had added the internet permission in manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```