# Android Crashing With Retrofit static Instance

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

When I use the static Retrofit object the application crashing with the below log
I cannot use the retrofit object without static because i am using it too often. Please let me know the workaround for the same

```
W/WindowAnimator: Failed to dispatch window animation state change.
        android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:513)
at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStopped(IWindow.java:548)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:302)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:694)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.access$000(WindowAnimator.java:56)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:128)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:698)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:630)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:882)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Some Time i get this error too

```
Fail to sendHttpRequest
                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP entity may not be null
                                                  at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:115)
                                                  at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:151)
                                                  at miui.util.ErrorReport.c(SourceFile:396)
                                                  at miui.util.ErrorReport.sendReportRequest(SourceFile:353)
                                                  at miui.util.ErrorReport$1.a(SourceFile:369)
                                                  at miui.util.ErrorReport$1.doInBackground(SourceFile:366)
                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is the retrofit object which is working fine

```
public static Retrofit getAPIClient(Context context) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(context.getString(R.string.base_url))
                .client(getOkHttpClient(context))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
                .build();
    }
```

But when I converted this to static it is crashing

```
     if ( appApiClient == null ) {
                appApiClient = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl( context.getString( R.string.base_url ) )
                        .client( getOkHttpClient( context)
                        .addCallAdapterFactory( RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create() )
                        .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create( getGson() ) )
                        .build();
       }
      return appApiClient ;
```

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930743/5110595)

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I have found the issue related to retrofit. please find my updated question

Comment: I can give you a better idea than

Comment: You are welcome @ABDevelopers

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RetroFitServiceGenerator {

    MySharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    public static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    public static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    private static Context context;

    private OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    public RetroFitServiceGenerator(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public <S> S serviceNOAuth(
            Class<S> serviceClass) {

        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        builder.client(httpClient.build());
        retrofit = builder.build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

Now you can modify or add Services based on your requirement like cache or authentication

and in your Class you just need to call :

```
 RetrofitAPI service = new RetroFitServiceGenerator(context).serviceNOAuth(RetrofitAPI.class);
```

Comment: than there is something other issue. post your retrofit whole code . even where you are calling the service and all

Comment: Please let me know what mistake i am doing in my code

Comment: Here is the way i used https://gist.github.com/askarali/8493830aba8951b18a00d6ce761c1e6b

Comment: on the first line only it is carshing ?

Comment: It is not even showing any log if we applied filter only to selected app ..if the filter is nofilter then only this error is showing

Comment: Can you please add to your git all the codes related to this like AppApiService and ApiClient

Comment: The error is not showing always after few api calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162071/discussion-between-abdevelopers-and-askarc-ali).